# Unzipping a .crx file on Raspbian does not work, works on macOS though

Tags: linux, macos, zip

I am trying to unzip a Chrome extension CRX file (which I understand are basically ZIP files) on a Raspberry Pi:

```
$ unzip -u -q cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx
warning [cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx]:  1322 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error: invalid zip file with overlapped components (possible zip bomb)
$ unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.
```

This works on macOS though:

```
$ unzip -u -q cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx
warning [cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx]:  1322 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
$ unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.
```

The MD5 sum of the CRX file is the same. So it seems that while the version of the program is the same, they work differently.

Is there any other way I can extract that file on the Pi?

I tried installing `p7zip`, but that does not work either:

```
$ 7zr e cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx

7-Zip (a) [32] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,32 bits,4 CPUs LE)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 3033491 bytes (2963 KiB)

Extracting archive: cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx
ERROR: cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx
Can not open the file as archive
```

For testing, you can download the extension [from here](https://standaloneinstaller.com/online-tools/crx-downloader) using the [URL of uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en).

Comment: vanilla 7zip seems to work, though that feels like a really old version you're using. Can you try the 'official' linux 7zip package here? https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those versions of unzip and p7zip seem.. terribly outdated, and I'm kinda wondering if the debian/raspian and mac builds were done with different flags or patches.

Anyway - Don't use p7zip. recently there's an official 7zip release that works on linux - [you're looking for the console version release](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

For Raspbian, download the `arm` version and extract it:

```
wget https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-linux-arm.tar.xz
mkdir 7z
mv 7z2201-linux-arm.tar.xz 7z
cd 7z
tar xvf 7z2201-linux-arm.tar.xz
sudo cp 7zz /usr/local/bin
```

Then you can use `7zz` globally on your system.

The syntax for extracting is something like:

```bash
7zz e -aoa -ocjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx
```

and it unzips the file fine. `-aoa` allows overwriting output files, and `-o` sets the output directory name.

Comment: Thanks, that did work. I added the specific commands necessary to extract the binary and unzip the file.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative I found that works under Raspbian and Ubuntu is the `7z` command that is available through the `p7zip-full` package:

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full
7z e -aoa -ocjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx
```

This version is also very much outdated but at least it extracts the file.

In case anyone needs a script that downloads and extracts an extension that works on macOS and Linux, [see here](https://gist.github.com/slhck/547773a8b1bd104e621e2a36b4960ef7).